# Is there is a way to fire mouseover event in amp-script (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, amp-html, web-worker, virtual-dom

There are some examples of using Javascript and Web Workers in AMP Documentation.
https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/?format=websites#script-hash

For example, I have a function that appends H1 after button click fired:

JS:

```
const button = document.getElementsByClassName('hello-url')[0];

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  h1.textContent = 'Hello World!';
  document.body.appendChild(h1);
});
```

AMP Virtual DOM:

```
<amp-script script="hello-world" class="sample">
  <button class="hello-url">Short button</button>
</amp-script>
```

When I am trying to use **mouseover** instead of **click** errors occurs:

> [amp-script] Blocked 2 attempts to modify DOM element children, innerHTML, or the like. For variable-sized  containers, a user action has to happen first.

> [amp-script] amp-script[script="hello-world"].js was terminated due to illegal mutation.

Note that I want to avoid using Jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `"mouseenter"` in your EventListener : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event

Comment: Unfortunatly same error with:
`button.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => { ... });`

Comment: Indeed, I made some research and it appears that you can encounter this error if your element doesn not have a fixed size : `<amp-script layout="fixed" height="300" script="myscript"></amp-script>`. Doc [here](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/#user-gestures)

Comment: That works! The only thing is that width has to be specified as well. BTW `layout="responsive"` works as well.